# EXTJS4 - get first record in a GridPanel

Tags: record, extjs4, gridpanel

I have a GridPanel in EXTJS4 with JSONstore. Like this:

```
var storeGridSpe = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore',{            
        proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'get-data-for-gridspe.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'rows',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'            
                }
            },          
            autoDestroy: true,
            fields: [
                 {name: 'specie'},
                 {name: 'conta'}
            ]
        });       

var GridSpe = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel',{
            store: storeGridSpe,
            id: 'gridspe',
            flex:1,
            autoScroll: true,
            columns: [         
                {id:'specie', header: "Specie", dataIndex: 'specie', flex:1},
                {id:'conta', header: "Selezioni", dataIndex: 'conta', width:75}
            ]       
        });
```

How can I get a value of the first GridPanel record? For example column "specie".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:
`storeGridSpe.first().get('specie')`

ExtJS4 has changed model querying a bit, so you may need to a tweak to get this to work exactly right.

Here's [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store), which pointed me to the `first()` method, and here's [Ext.data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Model), which indicated `get()` as the method to use.

`4.0.x` is still pretty volatile, so nothing or everything may work. :P

Comment: Now it works... but if I try to use that function in another js file like this:
var GridSpe=Ext.getCmp('gridspe');
console.log(GridSpe.getStore().first().get('specie'));

I see this error:
GridSpe.getStore().first() is undefined

Why? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are loading things up, you might need to wait until the grid's store's proxy has finished loading data e.g.

```
storeGridSpe.on('load',reactorFunction);
```